# Should I delete char arrays in .h files

Tags: c++, arrays, raii

How do I manage the char array `buffer` in Test.h?

Test.h

```
class Test{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();

    char buffer[255];
};
```

Test.cc

```
#include "Test.h"

Test::Test()
{
}

Test::~Test()
{
    // Do I need to delete/free buffer?
}
```

I understand that when `new` or `malloc` are used the memory must be released using `delete` or `free()`.

Is the char array `buffer` allocated on the stack for each instance of `Test` and so does not need to be deleted?

Comment: You never need to delete anything that wasn't returned from new.

Comment: Note that the information "in header" doesn't belong anywhere in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you do not need to delete it. Therefore you don't need a destructor (unless you have some other resource which needs to be released)

The rule is simple: each memory/object obtained with `malloc`/`new`/`new[]` should be freed/destroyed **once and only once** with the corresponding `free`/`delete`/`delete[]`. Nothing less. Nothing more.

Also, in modern C++, you rarely need to manage memory resources like this. You would use `std::vector` or another container, or if you really need pointers, you should use smart pointers, `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Is the char array buffer allocated on the stack for
each instance of Test and so does not need to be deleted?
```

Since `char buffer[255]` is a plain character array encapsulated within class `Test` so its *lifetime* is tied with object of `Test` class i.e. whenever object of class `Test` is created, the memory for array will be allocated and when object is destroyed, memory will be freed.

Hence, whether you create object of `Test` class on `stack` or `heap` (using `new`), when object will be destroyed (automatically or using `delete`), the memory occupied by array will be released.